# two columns of correlated pairs: remove rows of 'duplicates' to collapse dataframe into groups? (hard to describe)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset looking something like this: `df<- read.table(text="Var1    Var2
K1       K2
K3       K2
K7       K2
K7       K3
K5       K9
K4       K9", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

These are all pairs with a correlation of 1, and I'm looking to group them into clusters in order to collapse a larger dataset later. Is there a simple way of removing rows like `K7     K3` because they are part of the `K2` group. I want to be able to group rows later based on column 2, so I don't want any 'duplicates'   of like a `K3` group for example.

Edit: expected output

````
K1       K2
K3       K2
K7       K2
K5       K9
K4       K9```
````

Comment: Could you please provide your expected output

Comment: @IceCreamToucan this question is different from the one you associated it with, I did use that answer to remove duplicates like K1  K2  vs. K2  K1, and now this is a different question so can you remove that?

Comment: would the solution just be to remove the duplicates in column 1 possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i think i answered my own question with:
`newdf<-df[!duplicated(df$Var1),]`